# How would a Java array not be accessible by index?

Tags: java, arrays

The byte array is located in a in instance of a subclass of HashMap that I have named `obj`, and when I call these methods on it:

```
 Class c = obj.get("data").getClass();
 System.out.println(c.getName() + " is array " + c.isArray());
```

It prints

```
 [B is array true
```

From what I have read about the `[B` symbol, it means it is a byte array. However, when I try to call these methods on it

```
System.out.println(obj.get("data").length);
```

or

```
System.out.println(obj.get("data")[0]);
```

or

```
System.out.println(obj.get("data").get(0));
```

or

```
byte[] ar = (byte[]) obj.get("data");
```

The compiler complains because it says that `obj.get("data")`, which reflect says is an array, is actually only an Object and therefore does not have these available behaviors.

My basic question here is this:

*What exactly would the reflect method `isArray()` mean if not that it is an array?*

Comment: An object is a class instance or an array.

Comment: That cannot be true inasmuch as this object is an instance of Object and also returns true after its class calls `isArray()`

Comment: Peter, in java an array is an object. Show the definition of `obj`

Comment: I'd expect the first three not to work.  I'd expect the last one to work.  What error does that one give you?

Comment: (_Just because it's an array doesn't mean you don't have to cast it to an array type before you can do array operations on it._)

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't you know it - despite what I have said, I went back and tried the last and it went fine. Not completely sure where I was erring before (I'm positive I was getting a class cast exception there), but it seems to work fine now! Still, this is food for thought for me in that I have actually never casted arrays before.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
Class c = obj.get("data").getClass();
```

This returns the *runtime* class of whatever object was retrieved from the map.  However:

```
System.out.println(obj.get("data").length);
```

The compiler validates the expression based on the *compile time* (declared) class of the map. You have not shown us the declaration of the map, so we cannot determine the compile-time type returned by `get()`.

From the error message I'd assume it's

```
Map<String,Object> obj;
```

or even just a raw map declared without type parameters.

Since the compiler does not know the runtime type, it complains.

The solution is to declare the map as, for example

```
Map<String, byte[]> obj = new HashMap<>();
```